CREATE_FAILED: IamRoleLambdaExecution
my task use case is

Upload excel files from front end to s3 (done)

Create sqs queue to process excels uploads + dlq

Create producer and consumer lambda functions

Add s3 upload event trigger to producer lambda

Add SQS worker lambda to consumer lambda


Note don’t create anything manually from the aws console, every feature must be go through serverless framework
for that i have created below AWS cloud-formation c# template serverless.yml . when deploy locally it throws error
serverless.yml
service: deal-price-excel-upload
frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: dotnet6
  stage: ${sls:stage}
  region: eu-west-2

package:
  individually: true
  patterns:
    - '**/*'

functions:
  dealPriceExcelUploadProducer:
    handler: src/Handler/DealPrices/DealPriceExcelUploadProducer.Handler
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: ag-staging-buckets
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: uploads/deals/deal-price-excel
          existing: true

  dealPriceExcelUploadConsumer:
    handler: src/Handler/DealPrices/DealPriceExcelUploadConsumer.Handler
    events:
      - sqs: arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-2:${AWS::AccountId}:DealPriceExcelConsumerQueue
      # - sqs: arn:aws:sqs:${env:AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}:${AWS::AccountId}:DealPriceExcelConsumerQueue
  
  dealPriceExcelUploadConsumerDlq:
    handler: src/Handler/DealPrices/DealPriceExcelUploadConsumer.Handler
    events:
      - sqs: arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-2:${AWS::AccountId}:DealPriceExcelConsumerDLQ
      # - sqs: arn:aws:sqs:${env:AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}:${AWS::AccountId}:DealPriceExcelConsumerDLQ

resources:
  Resources:
    PermisionToS3AccessFunctionRole: 
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        RoleName: PermisionToS3AccessFunctionRole
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service: 
                  - lambda.amazonaws.com
              Action: 
                - 'sts:AssumeRole'
        Policies:
          - PolicyName: S3AndCloudWatchLogsPolicy
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: "2012-10-17"
              Statement:
                - Effect: Allow
                  Action:
                    - logs:PutLogEvents
                    - logs:CreateLogGroup
                    - logs:CreateLogStream
                  Resource: "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
                - Effect: Allow
                  Action:
                    - s3:GetObject
                  Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::ag-staging-buckets/*"
    
    DealPriceExcelConsumerQueue:
      Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
      Properties:
        QueueName: DealPriceExcelConsumerQueue
        RedrivePolicy:
          deadLetterTargetArn: !GetAtt DealPriceExcelUploadConsumerDlq.Arn

    DealPriceExcelUploadConsumerDlq:
      Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
      Properties:
        QueueName: DealPriceExcelUploadConsumerDlq

  Outputs:
    DealPriceExcelConsumerQueueURL:
      Description: URL of DealPriceExcelConsumer Queue
      Value: !GetAtt DealPriceExcelConsumerQueue.QueueUrl

    DealPriceExcelConsumerQueueARN:
      Description: ARN of DealPriceExcelConsumer Queue
      Value: !GetAtt DealPriceExcelConsumerQueue.Arn

    DealPriceExcelUploadConsumerDlqURL:
      Description: URL of dead-letter queue
      Value: !GetAtt DealPriceExcelUploadConsumerDlq.QueueUrl

    DealPriceExcelUploadConsumerDlqARN:
      Description: ARN of DealPriceExcelUploadConsumer Dlq
      Value: !GetAtt DealPriceExcelUploadConsumerDlq.Arn

Error response is
Deploying to stage dev
deal-price-excel-upload › waiting
deal-price-excel-upload › deploying
deal-price-excel-upload › Running "serverless deploy --stage dev"
deal-price-excel-upload › Running "serverless" from node_modules
deal-price-excel-upload › Deploying deal-price-excel-upload to stage dev (eu-west-2)
deal-price-excel-upload › × Stack deal-price-excel-upload-dev failed to deploy (30s)
deal-price-excel-upload › Environment: linux, node 20.10.0, framework 3.38.0 (local) 3.38.0v (global), plugin 7.2.0, SDK 4.5.1
deal-price-excel-upload › Credentials: Local, "default" profile
deal-price-excel-upload › Docs:        docs.serverless.com
deal-price-excel-upload › Support:     forum.serverless.com
deal-price-excel-upload › Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
deal-price-excel-upload › Error:
deal-price-excel-upload › CREATE_FAILED: IamRoleLambdaExecution (AWS::IAM::Role)
deal-price-excel-upload › Resource handler returned message: "The policy failed legacy parsing (Service: Iam, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 730862c6-b605-4c15-8b58-7c691fe36aa4)" (RequestToken: 0227d58a-8023-16c4-346a-986b9558862c, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
deal-price-excel-upload › 
deal-price-excel-upload › View the full error: https://eu-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=eu-west-2#/stack/detail?stackId=arn%3Aaws%3Acloudformation%3Aeu-west-2%3A590183890325%3Astack%2Fdeal-price-excel-upload-dev%2Fcfd04531-fc20-11ee-b794-0a739426bea1
deal-price-excel-upload › error
deal-price-excel-upload › Error:
deal-price-excel-upload › CREATE_FAILED: IamRoleLambdaExecution (AWS::IAM::Role)
deal-price-excel-upload › Resource handler returned message: "The policy failed legacy parsing (Service: Iam, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 730862c6-b605-4c15-8b58-7c691fe36aa4)" (RequestToken: 0227d58a-8023-16c4-346a-986b9558862c, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
deal-price-excel-upload › 
deal-price-excel-upload › View the full error: https://eu-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=eu-west-2#/stack/detail?stackId=arn%3Aaws%3Acloudformation%3Aeu-west-2%3A590183890325%3Astack%2Fdeal-price-excel-upload-dev%2Fcfd04531-fc20-11ee-b794-0a739426bea1
deal-price-excel-upload › 

please help me to sort out this error
